# What am I doing wrong in monit syntax with regex?

Tags: linux, monit

In my monitrc i wrote next:

```
check file mysite.com-access.log with path /var/log/apache2/mysite.com-access.log
        if content = "\/1.[01]\" 4(\d){2}" then alert
```

But the **systemctl status monit.service** says I have an error in syntax:

```
extsites monit[19043]:  * Starting daemon monitor monit
extsites monit[19043]: /etc/monit/monitrc:305: syntax error '\d'
extsites monit[19043]:    ...fail!
```

Earlier I put `"\/1.[01]\" [45](\d){2}"`, but error in syntax was in '[45]'.

What am I doing wrong? All my regex was right in https://regex101.com/.

Update:
I corrected my string as  `if content = "^\/1\.[01]\" [45](\d){2}" then alert` 
but syntax error there is still.

Comment: It seems I should use single quotes instead double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems we should use single quotes instead double.

Answer (score 0):

When I am correct, monit uses POSIX regex syntax.

So following this description: https://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html
... you could replace `\d` with `[:digit:]`

It's not logical to me, but maybe monit doesn't get the "`\`d" right

Following the ["content"-examples](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#FILE-CONTENT-TEST) in the monit-documentation, the double quote should not be the problem

Comment: "Following the "content"-examples in the monit-documentation, the double quote should not be the problem" - Yes, it so, but single quotes solved my problem. All alerts work and no any errors.

Comment: @DenisJun that is indeed interesting. I thought the question wasn't solved yet, but if you answered your own question, you can provide this as an answer and mark it as solved (maybe you could also open an issue here https://github.com/arnaudsj/monit/issues - so that this can be fixed or clarified)

Comment: it does not seem to be documented anywhere, but it seems that `\"` does not escape a double quote inside a double quote when using regex. What does, who know. However, as Denis discovered, if you use single quote instead of double to escape the whole thing, it works - also is not documented anywhere.

Comment: Looking at the source code, monit has a very weird notion of unquoting - it simply strips out all double quotes, single quotes and spaces from the beginning and from the end of string. There is no escaping for either single or double quotes.