# Despite trying posix regex, getting this error in monit

Tags: regex, linux, monit

I have this monit syntax,

```
check file access_log_1 with path /app/DNIF_logs/access_log_1
        ignore content = ".*favicon.*"
        if content = "^([:digit:]{1,3}\.){3}[:digit:]{1,3}[:space:]((((([:digit:]{1,3}\.){3}[:digit:]{1,3})|\-)[:space:]([:digit:]{6,7}|\-)[:space:][-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&=]*)[:space:])|)-[:space:]-[:space:]\[[:digit:]{2}\/([A-Z]|[a-z]){3}\/[:digit:]{4}\:[:digit:]{2}\:[:digit:]{2}\:[:digit:]{2}[:space:]\+[:digit:]{4}\][:space:]\"(.*)\"[:space:](500|502|503)([:digit:]|[:space:])*\"https?:\/\/(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&\/\/=]*)\"(.*)" then alert
```

While running this monit I'm getting this error

```
/monitrc:40: syntax error '.*'
```

I tried removing the first .* and got

```
monitrc:41: syntax error '"[:space:](500|502|503)([:digit:]|[:space:])*\"'
```

so got to know error is at the first occurance of (.*)
As per the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164129/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-monit-syntax-with-regex), we've to use posix regex syntax. Is there a different posix syntax for .* or what should I do?

Comment: Just added ''(single quotes) instead of ""(double quotes) at corners and it worked. Now my daemon is not starting with `./monit -c ../conf/monitrc` command, can anybody tell why??

Comment: With `[:digit:]` outside of bracket expressions, your regex is not POSIX compliant, just replacing `"` with `'` won't do here.

Comment: Please upvote/accept the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70256866/11329890) that helped you get to solution.

Comment: replace  the single quotes with `double quotes("")` and replace `[:digit:]` with `[0-9]`.
Given answer helped me with it, upvoted! :)

Answer (score 3):

In POSIX ERE,

- Bare POSIX character classes are not allowed, you should always use them inside *bracket expressions* (i.e. square brackets)
- Note `[[:digit:]]` is the same as `[0-9]`
- Inside bracket expressions, you can't use regex escapes, all literal backslashes are treated as literal backslash matching patterns
- `\b` is not recognized, but you can usually use `\<` as a starting and `\>` as a trailing word boundaries
- To use double quotes in the regex, use single quotes to delimit the regex string.

You may fix the regex like

```
if content = '^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}[[:space:]]((((([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})|-)[[:space:]]([0-9]{6,7}|-)[[:space:]][-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\>([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&=]*)[[:space:]])|)-[[:space:]]-[[:space:]]\[[0-9]{2}/[[:alpha:]]{3}/[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}[[:space:]]\+[0-9]{4}][[:space:]]"(.*)"[[:space:]](500|502|503)[0-9[:space:]]*"https?://(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\>([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_+.~#?&/=]*)"(.*)' then alert
```

Note:

- `([A-Z]|[a-z])*` is better written as just `[[:alpha:]]*` (any zero or more letters
- `([0-9]|[[:space:]])*` has a shorter variant, `[0-9[:space:]]*`.

Comment: finally got it working, by `[0-9]`, monit is not working on anything else. Thanks :)

Comment: @Akshat What about `[[:space:]]`? If you have issues with using POSIX character classes, this environment is just too buggy and there is no guarantee the regex will work in a stable way. Well, at least you can just use a space to match literal spaces.

Comment: About `[[:space:]]`, I simply used `\s` but same wasn't working for `\d`.. had to do it with `[0-9]`. Maybe monit version is too old or something.

Comment: @Akshat `\s` works in my Ubuntu for sure, but there are environments where shorthands are not supported, so I prefer to stay on the safe side when using `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: Will keep a note of it for next time. Thanks mate :)